# upsert operation using IdLookup

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcedx-cli, field-update, upsert, database.insert

I want to perform insert and upadate operation on Account on same record by using following query but It inserts two accounts with different descriptions

Account acct = new Account(Name = 'practice upsert',phone ='675122',description = 'updated record 1');
INSERT acct;

Account acct2 = new Account(Name = 'practice upsert',phone ='675122',description ='updated record 2');

upsert acct2 account.fields.ID;

How can I insert and update same record using IDLookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity is all about the `Id` field in Salesforce. So pass the `Id` from the `insert` (that is automatically set when that is done) into the `update`:

```
Account acct = new Account(
    Name = 'practice upsert',
    Phone = '675122',
    Description = 'updated record 1'
);
insert acct;

Account acct2 = new Account(
    Id = acct.Id,
    Name = 'practice upsert',
    Phone = '675122',
    Description ='updated record 2'
);
update acct2;
```